# UpdateCursor not updating when run from PyCharm?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, pycharm

I have a script in ArcPy that iterates through a set of intersection points and determines if all intersecting streets have the same attribute value in the CROSSLTS field, and if they do, sets the the intersection point's MarkForProcessing field value to 1. if the intersecting segments do not have identical CROSSLTS values, it sets the MarkForProcessing field value to 0.

When I run this script from the Python window of ArcMap, it takes 2 hours and I get an "out of memory" message before it completes. when i run it from PyCharm, it takes roughly 10 minutes, but the MarkForProcessing field is never updated.

Can someone could take a look?

```
import arcpy
workspace = 'C:\SRC\Bikestress\LTS classification.gdb'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

##check if all elements in a list are identical, returns true if so.
def checkEqual(lst):
    return lst.count(lst[0]) == len(lst)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'C:\SRC\Bikestress\LTS classification.gdb\Intersections','INTERSECTIONSLYR','',workspace)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r'C:\SRC\Bikestress\LTS classification.gdb\roadmidsplit2','STREETSLYR','',workspace)

Intersectionfields = ["CONTROLTYPE","GLOBALID","MarkForProcessing","SHAPE@"]
StreetsFields = ["CROSS_LTS"]

count = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('INTERSECTIONSLYR', Intersectionfields) as IntersectionCursor:
    for Intersection in IntersectionCursor:
        count += 1
        if Intersection[0] not in ["4STOP", "PED", "TRAFFICSIG"]:

            # select the intersection of the current row, and all adjacent segments
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('STREETSLYR', "INTERSECT", Intersection[3], "", "NEW_SELECTION")

            CROSSLIST = []

            #make sure selection is not empty
            desc = arcpy.Describe('STREETSLYR')

            if desc.FIDSet == '':

                with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('STREETSLYR', StreetsFields) as StreetCursor:
                    for Street in StreetCursor:
                        CROSSLIST.append(Street[0])

                if len(CROSSLIST) != 0:
                    if not checkEqual(CROSSLIST):
                        Intersection[2] = 1
                    else:
                        Intersection[2] = 0

            IntersectionCursor.updateRow(Intersection)
        if str(count)[-2:] == "00":
            print(str(count) + " records processed")
print('writing intersections layer...')
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("INTERSECTIONSLYR", r'C:\SRC\Bikestress\LTS classification.gdb\IntersectionsUpdated')
print("done")
```

Comment: Have you tried testing your code from IDLE?

Comment: Im pretty sure you cant use a geometry (SHAPE@) as selecting feature in SelectLayerByLocation. Instead create a feature layer for each row using object id and use the layer as selecting feature

Comment: @PolyGeo It didn't work in IDLE. Ill add that it DOES work when run straight from arcmap, but it takes a very long time and runs out of memory

Comment: What does this check?: `if desc.FIDSet == '':`

Comment: @BERA it checks that the street selection is not empty. i got an error about iterating through empty geometry before I put that line in

Comment: I cant find the help section for FIDSet but from other sources it looks like it should be a string holding the objectids of the selected features. So your if statements should not work as expected

Comment: oh right, it should be if desc.FIDSet != ''. good eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure why your code does not work or why you get memory error but you could try some things:

1. You dont need a function to check if all list elements are the same, use the set datatype which by definition cant contain duplicates. If len of the set is different from len of the list, you have duplicates
2. A geometry (SHAPE@) cant be used as selecting features, it must be a layer. Create a layer for each row instead using OID.
3. Indentent updateRow one level, no need to update row if you dont assign a new value.

#### Try using Spatial Join instead:

The reason your code is running so slow is that it has to execute Select By Location once for each row. Instead use Spatial Join to check the relationships once. Try:

[image]

Then:

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Default.gdb'

spatjoin = 'Intersections_SpatialJoin_Roads'
spatjoinfields = ['TARGET_FID','Roadname']

intersections = 'Intersections'
field_to_update = 'Roadcheck'

d = defaultdict(list)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(spatjoin,spatjoinfields) as cursor:
    for target_fid, roadname in cursor:
        d[target_fid].append(roadname)

updatedict = {}
for key,value in d.items(): #d.iteritems() in python2
    if None in value: #If no roads are found
        updatedict[key] = 3
    elif len(set(value))==1:
        updatedict[key] = 1
    else:
        updatedict[key] = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(intersections,['OID@',field_to_update]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in updatedict:
            row[1] = updatedict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, trying this now. it should take about an hour and a half at this rate (~16,000 entries), however, so I will get back to you later.

Comment: @Alex i have deleted the first code and added a way using Spatial Join. Try this instead.

Comment: I will add that when I ran the script in the arcgis python console, using @SHAPE DID work, but it did not work outside of arcGIS.

Thanks again!